# c# .net xml serialization retrieving value from xml element array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

I have the following example xml and I'm trying to deserialize the xml to get the value from the xml element array (the "READING" element), to get the "22.9" value below (it's hard to explain).

I can get all the other values out using XmlSerializer.

Example xml:

```
 <LIVE deviceid="1394602" utc="18-Oct-2016 01:22:28" local="18-Oct-2016 12:22:28">
       <READINGS type="full" probecount="1" portcount="2" discovery="2">
          <READING parameter="Temperature" shortparameter="Temp" unit="°C" channel="1" probeid="3" state="OK" probename="EC202" sensor="0">22.9</READING>
          <READING parameter="Ozone" shortparameter="O3" unit="ppm" channel="0" probeid="3" state="OK" probename="EC202" sensor="72">5</READING>
       </READINGS>
</LIVE>
```

Could I please get help for this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise it's really hard for us to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry, the code formatter didn't work ...

Comment: Please provide the code what you have tried so far. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string xml = @"<LIVE deviceid=""1394602"" utc=""18-Oct-2016 01:22:28"" local=""18-Oct-2016 12:22:28"">
       <READINGS type=""full"" probecount=""1"" portcount=""2"" discovery=""2"">
          <READING parameter=""Temperature"" shortparameter=""Temp"" unit=""°C"" channel=""1"" probeid=""3"" state=""OK"" probename=""EC202"" sensor=""0"">**22.9**   
          </READING>
       </READINGS>
</LIVE>";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LIVE));
            using(var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var live = (LIVE)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                var output = default(double);
                var text = Regex.Match(live.READINGS.READING.Text, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value;
                if (double.TryParse(text, out output))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(output);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "READING")]
    class READING
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "parameter")]
        public string Parameter { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "shortparameter")]
        public string Shortparameter { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "unit")]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "channel")]
        public string Channel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "probeid")]
        public string Probeid { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "state")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "probename")]
        public string Probename { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "sensor")]
        public string Sensor { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "READINGS")]
    class READINGS
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "READING")]
        public READING READING { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "probecount")]
        public string Probecount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "portcount")]
        public string Portcount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "discovery")]
        public string Discovery { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LIVE")]
    class LIVE
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "READINGS")]
        public READINGS READINGS { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "deviceid")]
        public string Deviceid { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "utc")]
        public string Utc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "local")]
        public string Local { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, XmlText was it - simple.